# MVC4 - How to upload a file partially (only the first 10 lines, for e.g.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fileapi

ASP.NET MVC - Is it possible to upload only the first 10 lines of a file? Basically, we have some files that can range from 1-10GB but the data that we need is present only in the first 10 rows in the file. Using the typical web development approache, we'd upload the whole file to the server and then read the first 10 rows, but uploading a 10GB file just to read a few bytes of data seems a big waste of resources. Is it possible to read such a file without uploading all of it to the webserver?

**Solution** - FileAPIs slice function solved this problem (thanks to Chris below). The simplified code is below for anyone interested -

```
var sampleFile = document.getElementById('yourfileelement').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileData = sampleFile.slice(0, 500000); //Read top 500000 bytes
reader.onprogress = function (evt) { //Show progressbar etc }
reader.onloadend = function (evt) { alert(evt.target.result); } //evt.target.result contains the file data that was read
reader.readAsText(fileClientReadData);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you may be able to accomplish it using the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) client-side to read and send to the server via AJAX just the first 10 lines. However, note that the File API is only [supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), so this won't work with IE 9 or less. You might be able to create a more comprehensive solution using a Flash or Java applet, but ugh.

Comment: Thank you,  FileAPIs, slice solved the problem. IE could be a problem, I suppose I'll have to add some alert message telling the users to upgrade the browser if needed.